# Reading undefined when trying to console.log a $scope variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm trying to make my first Angular app and so far everything is working good, I'm trying to do a bit of form validation and this is what I have so far:

```
angularsap.js:

var app = angular.module('PugMe', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', { 
        controller: 'HomePage', 
        templateUrl: '/partial/home' 
    })

    .when('/login', {
        controller: 'Login',
        templateUrl: '/partial/login'
    });
});

app.controller('HomePage', function($scope) {
    bgColor('white');
    active = 'link1';
});

app.controller('Login', function($scope) {
    bgColor('#eee');
    active = 'login';
    console.log($scope);

});
```

Then my

```
index.html

<html ng-app="PugMe">
    .. normal stuff ..
    <div ng-view>
    </div>
</html>
```

Then my

login.html

```
 <div class="container">
    <form class="form-signin" role="form" method='post' action='/login' name="loginForm" novalidate>
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <p class="alert alert-danger" ng-hide="loginForm.$valid">{{loginForm.email}}</p>
        <input name='email' ng-model="email", placeholder="Email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
        <input name='password' ng-model="password", type="text" class="form-control" required value="{{loginForm.email}}">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid">Sign in</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

My problem is I don't seem to have any `$scope` control, when I do

`console.log($scope)` it returns an object (see picture)
[image: <code>console.log($scope)</code> it returns an object (see picture)]

But if I do `console.log($scope.loginForm);` it returns `undefined`... Why is this I'm so confused. Look forward to replys thank you.

Edit: Ignore the random {{ }} variables they were just there for debugging.

My templates are in `.ejs` with a `node` backend, I don't know how important that is, but the files are saved as `.html` I added `app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);`

Update if I `console.log(this)` I get an empty object I don't know what this means.

Comment: @Dalorzo I think it's auto declared when in a form, you can see loginForm in the picture and if I click on it it will show other things

Answer (score 0):

The HTML is not loaded when the controller is loading , What you can do is to add `onLoad` event handler for ng-view.

```
<div ng-view  onload="onLoad()">


app.controller('Login', function($scope) {
    bgColor('#eee');
    active = 'login';
    console.log($scope);
    $scope.onLoad=function(){
      console.log($scope);
    }

});
```

Or if you do  `console.log($scope);` in some other event like `click` for a button then you will have the `form` loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This is because javascript uses objects, arrays and functions by reference, while all other types are treated by value.

In this particular case, when you try to console $scope.loginForm, it has not been defined yet, and at the console you see it because what you see is the reference on the console, which updates automatically.

If you try to do console.log(JSON.stringify($scope)); you will se that loginForm is not on the log.

A hack to check if this is a sync issue would be to add this in your Login controller

```
$timeout(function(){
    //whatever you want to do such as console.log($scope.loginForm);
}, 0);
```

This way AngularJS will wait until the current $digest cycle ends and start a new one right after executing the callback defined at $timeout